dh_auto_test Error (Lubuntu)
I am trying to restore typeahead behavior in my file picker by using this tutorial: https://blobfolio.com/2019/restoring-gtk3-typeahead-in-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine/
I got the patch, and the gtk3 source. Once I get to sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b in the tuturial, it runs for a while and seems to be doing a lot, but eventually it halts with the following errors (I tried twice, error both attempts):
make[2]: *** [Makefile:749: check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Target 'check' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/gtk3/gtk+3.0-3.24.20/debian/build/deb'
dh_auto_test: error: cd debian/build/deb && make -j12 check VERBOSE=1 -k check -j1 returned exit code 2
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:209: override_dh_auto_test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/gtk3/gtk+3.0-3.24.20'
make: *** [debian/rules:135: binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2

This is just the final lines of the output, there are probably thousands of lines from the multiple minutes it spent running. I just pasted the last few lines as they seem to be the only lines relevant to why it halted.
What is causing this and how do I resolve it? I have no experience with applying patches or building anything from source, so if possible please give me a hand-holding dumbed down answer.
Alternatively, is there another way to apply the patch instead of using dpkg-buildpackage?
OS: Lubuntu 20.04
Thanks
